# Need help in SQL query- date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with column whose values are as below:

```
202009
202010
202011
202012
202101
202102
202103
```

These are year and month. How can I update this so as to it increments month and also year at the end of dec?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  What does "increments month and also year at the end of dec" mean?  What is the datatype of the column?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want to add one month to each value.  If so, you can convert to a date and then back to a string or number.  So:

```
select t.*,
       format(convert(date, concat(col, '01'))), 'yyyyMM')
from t
```